# Check whether a file is an OSGi bundle (and find the bundle name) without installing it in the OSGi framework

Tags: osgi

Is it possible? Or do I have to try to install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about OSGi Release 4, since in OSGi Release 3 and earlier *any* valid JAR file was also a valid OSGi bundle.

Simply read the JAR's manifest using the standard Java APIs in the `java.util.jar` package. The minimum headers required to be a valid R4 bundle are:

- `Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2`
- `Bundle-SymbolicName: ...`

As BJ points out, the "id" of the bundle is assigned when it is installed, but what many people take to be the "id" is actually the Bundle Symbolic Name.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the Bundle-Name, or a host of Bunde-XXX properties within the **meta-inf/manifest.m**f jar file.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle id is assigned by the framework when the bundle is installed. Thus only an installed bundle has a bundle id.

Comment: Ah, so it's just Eclipse misusing terminology. I meant bundle name.